# Zariski's Main Theorem and Blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, blowup

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective schemes with $Y \subset X$. Let $\pi : \widetilde{X} \to X$ be the blow up of $X$ along $Y$ with exceptional divisor $E$.

I have seen the statement that Zariski's Main Theorem implies that   $\pi_{*}(\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} ) \to \mathcal{O}_{X}$  and $\pi_{*}(\mathcal{O}_{E}) \to \mathcal{O}_{Y} $ are isomorphisms. Why is this true?

References and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf) is a great reference if you're ever trying to figure out or remember when for a morphism $f:X\to Y$ we will have $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$.

Here's the relevant portion of that answer for this post, in order to make this answer self-contained:

> **The case of an arbitrary projective morphism.**
>
> Now when $f:X\to Y$ is any projective morphism, then $f_*\mathscr O_X$ is a coherent
>   $\mathscr O_Y$-module, hence we get a factorization of $f$ as $h\circ g:X\to Z\to Y$,
>   where $h:Z\to Y$ is affine, and where also $h_*(\mathscr O_Z) = f_*\mathscr O_X$.
>   Then $h$ is not only an affine map, but since $h_*(\mathscr O_Z)$ is a coherent $\mathscr
> O_Y$-module, $h$ is also a finite map.  Moreover $g:X\to Z$ is also projective and since
>   $g_*(\mathscr O_X) = \mathscr O_Z$, it can be shown that the fibers of $g$ are connected.
>   Hence an arbitrary projective map $f$ factors through a projective map $g$ with connected
>   fibers, followed by a finite map $h$.  Thus in this case, the algebra $f_*\mathscr O_X$
>   determines exactly the finite part $h:Z\to Y$ of $f$, whose points over $y$ are precisely
>   the connected components of the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$.
>
> One corollary of this is "Zariski's connectedness theorem".  If $f:X\to Y$ is projective
>   and birational, and $Y$ is normal then $f_*\mathscr O_X= \mathscr O_Y$, and all fibers
>   of $f$ are connected, since in this case $Z = Y$ in the Stein factorization described
>   above.  If we assume in addition that $f$ is quasi finite, i.e. has finite fibers, then
>   $f$ is an isomorphism.  More generally, if $Y$ is normal and $f:X\to Y$ is any birational,
>   quasi - finite, morphism, then $f$ is an embedding onto an open subset of $Y$ ("Zariski's
>   'main theorem' ").  More generally still, any quasi finite morphism factors through
>   an open embedding and a finite morphism.

This applies to your situation as follows: the blowup map $\pi:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is a projective birational map with connected fibers. Since projective and connected fibers are preserved under base change, we see that the base change of this map $E\to Y$ is again projective with connected fibers, so we may also apply the result there, via the Stein factorization described in the first paragraph (even though this last morphism is not birational - $\dim E=\dim X-1\neq \dim Y$).

Comment: Hi, KReiser @. Thank you very much for the support given in the questions I ask here in the forum.

Comment: KReiser@. I asked this question because I am trying to understand your answer and another about Direct Image and Blow up.

Comment: Hi, @KReiser. I will post a question to answer two questions I have about your answer in Direct Image and Blow up. thank you.